# Show existing value as pre-selected in drop down, radio buttons and checkboxes fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a network that I am building which groups freelancers together and allows potential customers to browse a profile containing their details.

In my database I store some values that the user will enter via a form using drop down or radio/checkbox fields. Through an edit page they can amend that data.

I'm struggling with how to get those fields pre-populated (if the value exists in the DB) with the value they've already made, probably at the time of creating their profile. I have managed to do it with the regular text/input fields by echoing out the column value as a form field value but can't figure out how to achieve it with these other fields.

***UPDATE: I need to pull the value from the database and have the form fields show that as the pre-selected/default entry.***

If I leave them blank it means the user will overwrite any existing data with nothing and in erase anything they've entered for that field before.

An example drop down field is below;

```
<div class="item-content">
<div>Experience</div>       
<select class="form-control" name="profile_experience" id="profile_experience">
    <option value="1">Amateur</option>
    <option value="2">Semi Professional</option>
    <option value="3">Professional</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I'm fetching the values with the following;

```
    <?php     
        $id=$_SESSION['user']['id'];
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user_id= :userid");
        $result->bindParam(':userid', $id);
        $result->execute();
        for($i=0; $currentprofile = $result->fetch(); $i++){  
    ?>
<!--FORM HERE-->
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: checked='checked',  selected='selected'

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the HTML. I need to get the value from the DB then have the drop down reflect that. I've updated my question to make that clearer.

Comment: How are you fetching your data from the database?

Comment: @Bruno via PHP through a loop. I've updated my question with the query code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve and stote the stored values

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT id FROM Tablename WHERE YOUR_CONDITION";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$selectedOption = $row['id'];
}
else
{
$selectedOption = ''; // Your default selection of $cc
}

$profile_experience_array = array(1=>'Amateur', 
                                  2=>'Semi Professional', 
                                  3=>'Professional');                                 
?>
```

The below code displays all the options of profile_experience_array. $key will check with the database value ($selectedOption) and that text will get selected by default.

```
<div class="item-content">
<div>Experience</div>       
<select class="form-control" name="profile_experience" id="profile_experience">
<option value="0">Select</option>
    <?php 
    foreach ($profile_experience_array as $key => $text)
    {
        if ($key == $selectedOption)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$key.'" selected="selected">'.trim($text).'</option>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.trim($text).'</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if a user hasn't completed that part of the form before - will the other values still be available for them to complete it?

Comment: If the user never completed any section it will go to the default value <option value="0">Select</option> (Edited Above)

Comment: Does that mean that I will need to populate my select values from a DB table, at the moment they are hardcoded. Will this approach also work checkboxes and radio buttons?

Comment: you can store the values in an Array.

Comment: For the checkboxes and radio buttons, change to the <option> tags in the echo to the corresponding input tag AND remove <select> tags

Comment: Thanks @Devs. I think I understand it now.

Comment: i've just tried it and for some reason it isn't working and causing my earlier query to break. There are several form fields on this edit page.

Comment: There was no error message - it was just defaulting to 'Please Select...' despite an entry existing in the table column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108913/discussion-between-ben-yates-and-devs).